# операция для каждого элемента в списке python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Создать функцию, которая принимает последовательность и знак. Например, func('+', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]). К каждому
элементу последовательности применяется данный знак, а после возвращается результат. Знаки: +, -,*,/

```
def test(s, a):
    if s == "+":
        sum_ = 0
        for i in a:
            sum_ += i
        return sum_

    if s == "-":
        count = 0
        sub = 0
        while count != len(a):
            count += 1
            sub = a[count- 1] - a[count]
        return sub
```

Подскажите,почему не получается?

Answer (score 4):

вот общий принцип (я не стал в функцию заворачивать)

основная идея - для каждой операции определить свою функцию и вызывать ее потом для всех элементов списка

```
# лямбда-функции для операций
signs = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
}

# текущая операция
sign = '*'

# текущий массив
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# применить операции ко всем элементам
res = arr[0]

for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    res = signs[sign](res, arr[i])

# вывести результат
print(res)
```

можно использовать `reduce` для облегчения кода:

```
from functools import reduce

# лямбда-функции для операций
signs = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
}

# текущая операция
sign = '*'

# текущий массив
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# применить операции ко всем элементам
res = reduce(signs[sign], arr)

# вывести результат
print(res)
```

P.S.

можно сделать через операторы (спасибо @5c0rp за замечание):

```
import operator

signs = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
}
```

Comment: Еще можно использовать `operator` вместо `lambda`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 1):

проблема здесь

```
sub = a[count- 1] - a[count]
```

вы в `sub` записываете разницу текущего и предыдущего элемента, но его самого нигде не используете

вам надо вначале в `sub` записать первый элемент списка и вычитать из него

```
count = 0
sub = a[0]
while count != len(a):
    count += 1
    sub -= a[count]
```